# Can ehcache diskstore be safely accessed concurrently?

Tags: java, concurrency, filesystems, ehcache

I see the DiskStore location has a .lock file. I've always understood that it is difficult and sometimes impossible to make file IO atomic. So, my expectation is that multiple applications cannot safely use the same ehcache DiskStore. However, the lock file makes me wonder. Performance bottlenecks aside, can it work?

Context: I'm wondering if two Java Servlet contexts running the same application could share a DiskStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

You could use [Terracotta server array](http://terracotta.org/documentation/bigmemorymax/terracotta-server-array/server-arrays) instead. Or, as a second alternative, a [replicated cache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/cache-topologies#replicated-caching) might suit you as well where each application / instance has it's own local DiskStore.

Comment: We're already using a replicated cache across two machines, but we also have multiple instances on the same machine. The part of your answer in parenthesis is what I'm interested in. Could you place that more prominently in your answer, then I'll set it as the accepted answer.