# Spring Security Inserting Acls: ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to get spring acl working. You can see below how I try to insert new entries into the MutableAcl. It works, as long as I only add one
at a time. But if I try to add multiple permissions (eg READ, WRITE), then I get a ConcurrentModificationException, see stack trace below). So it seems that there is a concurrency problem, so far I've been unable to determine how to prevent it. For testing purposes I added a Thread.sleep(1000); below the mutableAclService.updateAcl(acl); call and voila, suddenly
I could add multiple permissions, so it's clearly a problem regarding the MutableAclService or my use of it. Any ideas?

Greetings, Nanoquack.

Code for inserting an ACL:
    @Autowired
    private MutableAclService mutableAclService;

```
public void addPermission(Object entity, Serializable identifier, Sid recipient, Permission permission) {
    MutableAcl acl;
    ObjectIdentity oid = new ObjectIdentityImpl(entity.getClass(), identifier);
    try {
        acl = (MutableAcl) mutableAclService.readAclById(oid);
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        acl = (MutableAcl) mutableAclService.createAcl(oid);
    }
    acl.insertAce(acl.getEntries().size(), permission, recipient, true);
    mutableAclService.updateAcl(acl);
    log.debug("Added permission. Entity: " + entity + " Recipient: " + recipient + " Permission: " + permission);
}
```

Stack Trace when trying to insert multiple ACLs:

```
25565 [acl%0043ache.data] ERROR net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory - Disk Write of org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl[Type: com.coderunner.caliope.module.caliope.model.Page; Identifier: 0] failed:
net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Failed to serialize element due to ConcurrentModificationException. This is frequently the result of inappropriately sharing thread unsafe object (eg. ArrayList, HashMap, etc) between threads
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.serializeElement(DiskStorageFactory.java:401)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.write(DiskStorageFactory.java:381)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$DiskWriteTask.call(DiskStorageFactory.java:473)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$PersistentDiskWriteTask.call(DiskStorageFactory.java:1067)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$PersistentDiskWriteTask.call(DiskStorageFactory.java:1051)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:713)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1541)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1506)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1541)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:439)
Hibernate: delete from acl_entry where acl_object_identity=?
    at net.sf.ehcache.Element.writeObject(Element.java:851)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at net.sf.ehcache.util.MemoryEfficientByteArrayOutputStream.serialize(MemoryEfficientByteArrayOutputStream.java:97)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.serializeElement(DiskStorageFactory.java:399)
    ... 11 more
```

Spring ACL Configuration:
      
        
        
        
          
            
              
                
                  ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR

```
  <bean id="aclService"
    class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    <constructor-arg ref="lookupStrategy" />
    <constructor-arg ref="aclCache" />
    <property name="classIdentityQuery" value="SELECT @@IDENTITY" />
    <property name="sidIdentityQuery" value="SELECT @@IDENTITY" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="expressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator" />
    <property name="permissionCacheOptimizer">
      <bean
        class="org.springframework.security.acls.AclPermissionCacheOptimizer">
        <constructor-arg ref="aclService" />
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="permissionEvaluator"
    class="org.springframework.security.acls.AclPermissionEvaluator">
    <constructor-arg ref="aclService" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="webexpressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />

  <bean id="aclCache"
    class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.EhCacheBasedAclCache">
    <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
        <property name="cacheManager">
          <bean
            class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />
        </property>
        <property name="cacheName" value="aclCache" />
      </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

Comment: `Failed to serialize element due to ConcurrentModificationException. This is frequently the result of inappropriately sharing thread unsafe object (eg. ArrayList, HashMap, etc) between threads ` Try setting a breakpoint on java.util.ConcurrentModificationException, find the ArrayList which causes problems, add the code of the class that uses ArrayList to the question - obviously this class is not thread safe or not supposed to be threadsafe => should not be serialized or something like that.

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. It seems to be the ArrayList which holds the ObjectIdentityImpls. But I was rather asking for a possible solution than for an explanation; the explanation is pretty clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you're using the Ehcache-based AclCache (which is used by the MutableAclService) and Ehcaches disk store appears to have a concurrency issue.

How does your Ehcache configuration look like? Have you tried using memory store (rather than disk store)?

Comment: Ah! Is this possible? How can I do that? I've edited my answer and added the spring acl configuration there.

Comment: In ehcache config (ehcache.xml). You omitted the aclCache bean definition. What does your ehcache.xml look like or are you using the defaults (fallback configuration)? Also are you using an up-to-date version of ehcache?

Comment: Interestingly enough, the aclCache bean definition was in the edit but soverflow didn't show it. I've re-appended it to the end of the bean defs, now it's visible. I don't have an ehcache.xml so I guess I'm using the fallback. My pom states that the project is using Version 2.7.2 of ehcache.

Comment: Right. What I would try: 1) If Spring sec 3.1.x, use the non-deprecated constructor for the aclCache bean 2) Downgrade ehcache to see if that helps (you're running a very recent version, maybe spring sec is lagging behind in its support for ehcache) 3) Modify ehcache.xml to not use disk store (if applicable)

Comment: Also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245813/can-ehcache-diskstore-be-safely-accessed-concurrently